# Formula for the $n$-th term of the sequence $1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 16, 24, 30, 60, 72, 96, 112, \ldots$, where $f_n := \frac{1}{n} (f_{2n} - f_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, real-numbers, generating-functions

I'm struggling with this sequence.

$$1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 16, 24, 30, 60, 72, 96, 112, \ldots$$

Where, $f_n := \frac{1}{n} (f_{2n} - f_n)$

You can also work it out for negative powers of 2,

$$f_\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{3}$$

$$f_\frac{1}{4} = \frac{8}{15}$$

$$f_{2^{-n}} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} (\frac{2^k}{2^k +1})$$

I wanted to know if it possible to find a formula for $f_n$, and to generalize it to all real numbers?

Can generating functions help here? (I don't know much about them.)

(And sorry if I had made some mistake)

Comment: https://oeis.org/A171609

Answer (score 1):

Using the [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), if $f_1=1$,
$$ f_n=(-1;2)_{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}$$

If $n=2^k$, $f_k=(-1;2)_k$ which generates the sequence $A028361$ in $OEIS$

Answer (score 1):

You asked about the sequence

$$1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 16, 24, 30, 60, 72, 96, 112, \ldots$$

which is the [OEIS sequence A171609](https://oeis.org/A171609).
It has a recursion with
$$f_1 = 1,\;\; f_{2n} = (n+1)f_n,\;\; f_{2n+1} = (n+1)f_{n+1}.$$

The question asked

> I wanted to know if it possible to find a formula for $f_n$, and to generalize it to all real numbers?

I doubt very much there is a simple formula for $f_n$ depending on what
you consider a "formula". I also doubt very much that it can be extended
to *all* real numbers. However, as you indicated, it can be uniquely
extended to all positive
[dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational). That is, rationals whose denominator is a power of $2$ using the
[q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) as

$$ f_{k/2^n} := f_k/(-k/2;1/2)_n $$ if $k$ is *any* odd positive
integer and $n$ is *any* integer positive or negative.

In case you are interested, I wrote
[PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)
code to compute $f_n$ for dyadic rationals:

```
{f(n) = if(n<=0, 0, n==1, 1, frac(n), a(2*n)/(1+n), 
      n%2, (1+n)/2*a((1+n)/2), 1, (1+n/2)*a(n/2))};
```